# Есть ли функция WinAPI c++ которая может зафиксировать движение мыши

Tags: c++

Что я имею ввиду, например если я дернул мышкой, то это фиксируется и например заносится в переменную boolean (movebymouse = true)

Comment: В **языке** C++ такой функции нет. Но такие функции есть в библиотеках (графических). Уточните, что именно вы используете.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ладно, я тогда и другой вопрос задам если сможете помочь.) Дело в том, что в своей программе хотел использовать функцию kbhit() на выключение бесконечного цикла, а сам бесконечный цикл нажимает курсором в какую-либо точку. Но так как он нажимает курсором, окно становится не активным, и я не могу завершить цикл. Я пытался сделать его активным через winapi, но ничего не получилось. Вот и пришла идея чтобы цикл выключался на дергание мышкой

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, указав, что используете WinAPI и тому подобное.

Comment: Если пишете кликер, то стандартным решением будет повесить старт/стоп на глобальные хоткеи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BOOL WINAPI GetCursorPos(
  _Out_ LPPOINT lpPoint
);
```

Состояние окна не должно влиять на выполнение кода

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648390(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

В самом языке и стандартной библиотеке такой или подобной функции нет.

Comment: Очень жаль, спасибо